# Search script that searches a txt file and prints or echos results

Tags: php, mysql, excel, search

I have parts website that I need to update the search script for. I have an Excel sheet with 3 columns, Part No, Part Name, and Page Number. I just want to create a simple search box and when an entry is made and you click submit it searches through the txt list and displays/echos/prints on the web page any lines of the txt file that correspond, be it part number or description name. It is to help people locate a part and then link them to the page of a catalog it can be found on - so the page number is a link to the page.

This search script below does exactly what I need it to do, I did not write it, it was written by a former employee - it connects to a mySQL db - BUT I cannot do that anymore, the mySQL is on a shared hosting service and the minimum character search is set to 4 and cannot be modified. I need to be able to search 3 character words such as 'oil', 'brm', 'rod'.

I've been trying for a few days to find an alternative method. I would like to be able to connect or search the txt or Excel file that contains the list of part numbers and the page they can be found on and NOT have it connect to the mySQL db.

I don't know how to modify this to have it connect to a txt file instead of the mySQL db.
Is that even possible?  Do I need to use a different kind of script?

I appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

```
<?php

if ($_POST['action'] =="search") {

  function make_page_url($pageno) {
    return "../vwcatalog/2013/" . $pageno . ".html";
  }

  echo "<tr><td>Search Results : (HINT-If Nothing Is Listed Below, Try the Table of Contents at the Bottom of the Page<br>
Search Hint: If necessary, try using singular words, instead of plural, i.e.; 'seat' - instead of 'seats'.)</td></tr>\n";

  $dbsearchlink=mysql_connect($db["host"],$db["user"],$db["pass"]) 
     or die("Failed to make database connection: " . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($db["used"]) 
    or die("Failed to select database: " . mysql_error());

  $query=sprintf("select partno,description,pageno from part_to_page where year=2013 and match(partno,description) against ('%s')", 
         mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchfor']));
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());

  echo "<tr><td><table>\n";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $url=make_page_url($row['pageno']);

    echo "\t<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['partno'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=$url>" . $row['description'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</table></td></tr>\n";

  mysql_free_result($result);
  mysql_close($dbsearchlink);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just switch the query

```
if(strlen($_POST['searchfor']) < 4){
$query=sprintf("select partno,description,pageno from part_to_page where year=2013 and ( partno LIKE '\%%s\%' OR description LIKE '\%%s\%')", 
         mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchfor']), 
         mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchfor']));
} else {
$query=sprintf("select partno,description,pageno from part_to_page where year=2013 and match(partno,description) against ('%s')", 
         mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchfor']));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! How do I modify this script so it does not want to connect to the mySQL db and it searches the txt file?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The mySQL database is perfectly suited to do exactly what you need with this updated query. Just import your data in to your database.

Comment: I edited the file with what you supplied, but it is still not finding 3 character words... ?

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I can search 3 character words??